# DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Invalid JSON response

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I am aware that there have been similar questions raised before and answers provided. I did go through them but either due to my poor experience/knowledge I was not able to find solution for my problem.

I am using DataTables and got this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=DT_load - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I went through the documentation on the website and the diagnostics but still struggle to work it out. It worked on localhost but when I deployed it on the web server, it broke. I used to get the 404 error but when I switched to Named Handler methods, the above error appeared with 200 status code. Below you will find my code:

```
**systemList.js**

$(document).ready(function () {
    
     $('#DT_load').DataTable({
       
     
        
        ajax: {
            url: "?handler=SystemsAll",
            type: "GET",          
            dataSrc: '',
            dataType: "json",
            
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            
            visible: false,
            searchable: false
        }],
        columns: [
            { "data": "name", "width": "10%"},
            { "data": "website", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "wiki", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "lastDeployed", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "sql", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "web", "width": "10%" },

            {
                data: "id",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    return `<div class="text-center">
                        <a href="/AppPages/Update?id=${data}" class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
                            Update
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <a class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
                            onclick=Delete('/api/system?id='+${data})>
                            Delete
                        </a>
                        </div>`;
                }, width: "40%"
            }
        ],
            
        language: {
           emptyTable: "no data found"
        },
        width: "100%"
    });
    
}


**HomeController.cs**

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ServiceCatalogue.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

namespace ServiceCatalogue.Controllers
{

    [Produces("application/json")]


    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public HomeController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        

        
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSystemsAll()
        {
           //var allData = await _db.SystemAsset.ToListAsync();
          // return new JsonResult(allData);
           
           return Json(new { data = await _db.SystemAsset.ToListAsync() });
        }

       
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int id)
        {
            var systemFromDb = await _db.SystemAsset.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
            if (systemFromDb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while Deleting" });
            }
            _db.SystemAsset.Remove(systemFromDb);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful" });
        }

        
        
    }
}


**Index.chtml**

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ServiceCatalogue.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

namespace ServiceCatalogue.Controllers
{

    [Produces("application/json")]


    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        private readonly AppDbContext _db;

        public HomeController(AppDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        

        
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSystemsAll()
        {
           //var allData = await _db.SystemAsset.ToListAsync();
          // return new JsonResult(allData);
           
           return Json(new { data = await _db.SystemAsset.ToListAsync() });
        }

       
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int id)
        {
            var systemFromDb = await _db.SystemAsset.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
            if (systemFromDb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while Deleting" });
            }
            _db.SystemAsset.Remove(systemFromDb);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete successful" });
        }

        
        
    }
}

**Startup.cs**

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using ServiceCatalogue.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;



namespace ServiceCatalogue
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CatologueDb")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc()
           .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new DefaultContractResolver());
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I forgot to add the detail from the DevTools
Request URL: http://webuat/RumenTest?handler=SystemsAll&_=1660638334549
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.146.16.194:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: I suggest you could use F12 network to see what the server return to the client, then we could continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you, I created an API controller from scratch and set up the api Route that AJAX could use and it worked..well, to an extent but at least now I can see in the DevTools the JSON object with all of the data. The problem now is that it is not rendering the data onto the Table

Comment: The data format is same as your test inside the local? I mean you could also use the same data to check if it will work well inside the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by simply removing the controller as it is Razor Page application and not a MVC one. Doing so I used the Name Handler directly in the PageModel class of the razor page where I wanted to render the Data Table. And also make sure you bind the property.

```
[BindProperty]
        public SystemAsset SystemAsset { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ServerAsset> ServerAsset { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSystemsAll()
        {
            var allData = await _db.SystemAsset.ToListAsync();
            return new JsonResult(allData);

            
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int id)
        {
            var asset = await _db.SystemAsset.FindAsync(id);
            if (asset == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _db.SystemAsset.Remove(asset);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
```

Another problem I needed to fix was the name of the columns in my AJAX call, they need match exactly the name of the columns in the database table.

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "?handler=SystemsAll",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": '',
            "dataSrc": '',
            "datatype": "jsonp",

        },
        
        "columns": [
            
            { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "Website", "name": "Website", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "Wiki", "name": "Wiki", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "LastDeployed", "name": "LastDeployed", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "Sql", "name": "Sql", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "Web", "name": "Web", "width": "10%" },
```

Another silly thing that I have missed was to clear out the cache on the browser as it sometimes renders a cached version.

Hope this helps other people.